# Why do I need to add [i-1] to get the loop to iterate over the array correctly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I understand that using a for of loop, I can just `console.log(i)` right away but while I was learning it at first, I tinkered around with the code and got it to work by adding a "-1" and I would like to know why it works.

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
sum = 0
for(const i of numbers) {
    sum = numbers[i-1]
    console.log(sum) 
}
```

the output for the above code is 1,2,3,4,5 and the output without the -1 will be 2,3,4,5,undefined.

Can someone explain to me why this happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing and mixing the usages of `for-of` and `for-in`. `for-in` will iterate over every *index* in the array*, whereas `for-of` will iterate over every *value* in the array. As such, looping through your array with `for-in` results in the indices "0, 1, 2, 3, 4", and using `for-of` results in the values "1, 2, 3, 4, 5". The latter cannot be used to index the array since arrays are 0-based, meaning the largest valid index is 4.

So you should do one or the other:

`for-of`:

```js
for (const i of numbers) {
    sum = i
    console.log(sum) 
}
```

`for-in`:

```js
for (const i in numbers) {
    sum = numbers[i]
    console.log(sum) 
}
```

---

*: As pointed out, `for-in` is a bit more complicated than just iterating through the indices of an array. A more complete explanation is that it iterates through all the property keys of an object, and for an array that happens to be its indices. You can also use it to get object keys, instance properties and method names, and other such things.

As a result, using `for-in` on an array is considered somewhat of a bad practice since if you or a library you imported inserted additional instance properties onto arrays, those properties would be included in the iteration and would likely break your program when you tried to access `array["someKey"]` (since it would presumably contain a different kind of data than the number-keyed bits). Instead, you should use `for-of`, `Array.forEach`, or `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` to confidently access the indices or values of an array.

Comment: You should mention the difference between for-of and for-in

Comment: @Samathingamajig I do, in the second sentence.

Comment: But it's not entirely correct. for-in also does properties on your array if you add them

Comment: @Samathingamajig I've added a footnote explaining the semantics of `for-in` in more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much man. @Abion47. This has been greatly informative!

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
for (const i of numbers)
```

`i` takes the values of the array and **not** the indices. Hence, `i` will take the values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. So you are printing the items with those indices. The first four of those are defined, while the last simply does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`const i of numbers` will give you each of the numbers in the list, 1-5.

The square brackets (`numbers[x]`)will index the list - give you the value at that index `x`.

Indexing in JS (and most languages) begins with 0, so the "addresses" in that list are 0-4, which is why if you ask for the item at 5, that is past the end of the list.

That's why you needed to -1: to not go past the end of the list.

Try putting some other values in "numbers" and you'll see.

Answer (score -1):

sum is being set to the VALUE within the numbers array and not its index.
so on loop 1, i = 1 (not zero), but you adjust this with your "sum = numbers[i-1]" so sum = numbers[0], resulting in your console log of "1" -> this is the value in the numbers array at index i.
Another way to loop through and print the array would be to run your for loop with an argument of (let i = 0, i < numbers.length, i++)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with this question, but in the future please refrain from posting an answer that restates the information given in others' answers.

Comment: sry! had to answer some "community questions" as part of a boot camp assignment. wont happen again.

Answer (score -2):

Array indexing starts from 0. If it is -1, then only one incremental value index will start from 0 to 4.